# How to use curl to get a GET request exactly same as using Chrome?

Tags: curl, browser, httprequest, user-agent, simulate

I have a web api `http://something.com/api` and I want to use GET to get the response body.

This is my command:

```
curl "http://something.com/api"
```

Of course, it fails and gives an error message.

When I use Chrome and input the above url, everythings correct. However I do the same things with Firefox, the url gives me the same error message. I try to repeat the action with Chrome extension DHC, the request gives correct response again. After some searching, I believe that the curl option `--user-agent` makes a difference. What is the correct way to set the user agent to Chrome? Or this is not the point, the problem comes from other fields? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

If you need to set the user header string in the curl request, you can use the `-H` option to set user agent like:

```
curl -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760694/how-to-use-curl-to-get-a-get-request-exactly-same-as-using-chrome
```

Updated user-agent form newest Chrome at 02-22-2021

---

Using a proxy tool like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) really helps make short work of something like what you are asking. Here is what I do, using this SO page as an example (as of July 2015 using Charles version 3.10):

1. Get Charles Proxy running
2. Make web request using browser
3. Find desired request in Charles Proxy
4. Right click on request in Charles Proxy
5. Select 'Copy cURL Request'

[image: Copy cURL Request example in Charles 3.10.2]

You now have a cURL request you can run in a terminal that will mirror the request your browser made. Here is what my request to this page looked like (with the cookie header removed):

```
curl -H "Host: stackoverflow.com" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36" -H "HTTPS: 1" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: https://www.google.com/" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.6,es;q=0.4" -H "If-Modified-Since: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 20:31:28 GMT" --compressed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760694/how-to-use-curl-to-get-a-get-request-exactly-same-as-using-chrome
```

Comment: It would be so much better if Charles supports copying/exporting multiple cURL requests in one go

Comment: Some APIs, such as ArcGIS, will only respect the `Accept: text/html` header to force HTML output.

Comment: curl -A agent_name is a short cut

Comment: You may need `-L, --location` to handle page redirection.

Answer (score 42):

Open Chrome Developer Tools, go to Network tab, make your request (you may need to check "Preserve Log" if the page refreshes). Find the request on the left, right-click, "Copy as cURL".

Comment: But cookie in "Copy as cURL" expires within few minutes. At least in case of most of the sites. 
How i can automate it to fetch new cookie ?

Comment: Similar option is available in FireFox: open Developer Tools -> Network tab, then right-click on the request and open "Copy Value" sub-menu

Answer (score 9):

Check the HTTP headers that chrome is sending with the request (Using browser extension or proxy) then try sending the same headers with CURL - Possibly one at a time till you figure out which header(s) makes the request work.

curl -A [user-agent] -H [headers] "http://something.com/api"

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Can you give me some real examples for setting user-agent to chrome and possible headers?

Comment: For anyone who may not familiar with this. `curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36" "http://something.com/api"`.