# Is incoming post Curl or html form

Tags: php, curl, post

Is there a way to find out if the incoming POST is coming from html form post or  a server to server post (curl for example)?

Comment: You need to set an identifier as parameter (or) use special custom headers (or) check the `host-header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way, but be mindful it can be easily masked and overridden by the HTTP client so its not reliable.

You're looking for the `User-Agent` header.  cURL will default to `User-Agent: curl/7.54.1` while web browser will default to a description of their browser.  Well... often. Some browsers will fake their UA because some website do [browser detection not feature detection](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/feature-detection-vs-browser-detection/) which despite being a bad idea, is still pretty widespread.

In PHP you can retrieve the user agent from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.  For example if I run `curl -sS https://mywebsite.dev/example.php`, then example.php will have `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` be somewhat similar to `curl/7.54.0`.

The User-Agent header (like all client request headers) can be easily faked. Using cURL I could easily send a fake header. Take this command for example:

```sh
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760694/how-to-use-curl-to-get-a-get-request-exactly-same-as-using-chrome
```

(yes - check out that SO answer too).

Given this example, your server code would have *absolutely no idea* if it was a web browser or cURL making this request.  You might be able to go on other signals such as cookies and other headers but they can be faked too.

Given that the User-Agent header is so frequently masked its probably not the most reliable thing to be basing your code on.  For example if you're building an API and you want to figure out if its your own application or someone else calling your API then you want to rely on things like API tokens, authentication and other custom headers to provide stronger trust signals to your app... but thats beyond the scope of your question.

So TLDR; yes - you can use the `User-Agent` header to determine the calling application... but don't rely on it.

Comment: And to followup - while $_SERVER is available in raw php, most modern frameworks will provide you a safer abstraction for accessing things like request headers and parameters; I defer to your framework of choice's documentation for implementation details.

Comment: It has to do with a payment api so it must be 100% reliable. It seems that i must use the auth method on the headers.

Comment: In which case the purpose of your question is 'how to secure an HTTP endpoint'. You'll find lots of ways for securing APIs here on SO and the rest of el Google.

Comment: no its not for secure reasons. 
Its for how i will respond to them. For server2server i just need to print them the results but in case they come through html form i have to do a redirection

Comment: If you wish to vary the response based on the client, be explicit about the content negotiation and use the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers. Keep it simple and don't vary the response based on the `User-Agent` (see browser v feature detection in my answer)