# is Vaadin Ready For Three Digits User Agent Strings

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin21

We are using Vaadin 7, 14 and 21.
I am curious about the upcomming 3 digits browser version

https://web.dev/chrome-firefox-100/

Is vaadin will have any issues withe the browser version change? or how can we test that?

thanks and best regards

I am trying to find a test algorithm to test the vaadin framwork if the browser version change to three digits.

Comment: Please read the link posted to explore the Problem that might appear and understand the potential problems.  Vaadin framework  must be using some ua-parsing library.

Comment: Here is the list of broken ua-string detection list :https://www.otsukare.info/2022/01/14/broken-ua-detection

Comment: It seems you might be right. [Here](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/e143153ab8e5db9f27af06232c1d7926e809f107/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/shared/BrowserDetails.java#L166) it says that if it is Firefox, the version string is five digits. Good intuition. The test should be simple: just make a request to your application with a [faked user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28760694/how-to-use-curl-to-get-a-get-request-exactly-same-as-using-chrome), and have your application display the browser version it detects.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, how did you find the code point in github, I would like to find the same for the version 7 of vaadin framework. :-)

Comment: Here's the [same file](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/blob/7.0/flow-server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/shared/BrowserDetails.java#L166) at tag `7.0`. As to how I found it, googled for "vaadin browser version", found API docs for `BrowserDetails`, googled for "github vaadin BrowserDetails", then read the code.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to test this is to install Chrome Canary today and use your application with that. It is version 102 already.

Test your real application, not only some of the libraries/frameworks you are using.

Answer (score 0):

[image: tested with vaadin 7]

I have tested our application build with with vaadin 7 Framework. atleast the framework is parsing the major version correctly. now as the Artur mentioned. All other code point which are somehow parsing the ua-agent string must be teseted as well. In vaadin serverside you can test it with the following code snipet:

```
Page.getWebBrowser().getBrowserMajorVersion()
```